# Concat across different tables - mysql/php stack

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I have three tables:

```
    Apples

ID|Name
1 |Granny
2 |Red
3 |Delicious

Pies
ID|Name|Apple_ID|Maker_ID
1 |Pie |1       |1
2 |Pie2|1       |2
3 |Pie3|1       |3
4 |Pie4|2       |1


Makers
ID|Name
1 |Jeff
2 |Jerry
3 |Jeremy
```

As you can see, an apple can be in three different pies, but is connected to different makers.
I want a query that I am preparing for export in CSV that does the following:

I want to get one apple per row with columns for the **apple ID, name and the makers names** in columns, but not the "interim" link between the two tables, Pies. so like this:

```
Granny, Jeff, Jerry, Jeremy
Red, Jeff
```

etc... I know I can do one query for all pies, then another for all makers, but I wonder if there was a way to concat the values from the last table as if they were in the same "row".  I also know I can just have many rows with the same values, but its preparing for somebody who wants to just look at the apple and right away know who makes a pie from it, and not scan multiple rows.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT CONCAT( Apples.name, ', ', GROUP_CONCAT(Makers.name SEPARATOR ', ') )
FROM Apples
JOIN Pies ON (Pies.Apple_ID = Apples.ID)
JOIN Makers ON (Makers.ID = Pies.Maker_ID)
GROUP BY Apples.name
```

Check the [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) manual page. Fiddle with its parameters to format its output as you like.

Comment: Yippee you guys are amazing! And then would i just `explode` the resulting string for an array for `fputcsv` or is there away for mysql to already give it to me arrayified?

Comment: I might add an `ORDER BY` in the `GROUP_CONCAT` to make the results deterministic. If we want to avoid any duplicate `Makers.name`, a DISTINCT keyword could also be added... `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Makers.name ORDER BY Makers.name SEPARATOR ', ')`

Comment: @dama_do_bling This actually produces a one-column, already-coma-separated result that you could write as-is into your CSV file. You don't even need `fputcsv()` here.

Comment: @RandomSeed So helpful! Out of curiosity, how would I do it so everything would be in array/columns if, say, I wanted to add something in a foreach loop or something?

Comment: You cannot build a query that returns a variable number of columns (eg. assuming an arbitrary number of `Makers` for one given `Apple`).